# Future map's (waiting) execution context. Stops execution with FixedThreadPool

Tags: scala, concurrent.futures, executioncontext

```
   // 1 fixed thread

   implicit val waitingCtx = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))

    // "map" will use waitingCtx

    val ss = (1 to 1000).map {n => // if I change it to 10 000 program will be stopped at some point, like locking forever
      service1.doServiceStuff(s"service ${n}").map{s =>
        service1.doServiceStuff(s"service2 ${n}")
      }
    }
```

Each `doServiceStuff(name:String)` takes 5 seconds. doServiceStuff does not have implicit ex:Execution context as parameter, it uses its own ex context inside and does `Future {blocking { .. }}` on it.

In the end program prints:

```
took: 5.775849753 seconds for 1000 x 2 stuffs
```

If I change 1000 to **10000** in, adding even more tasks : `val ss = (1 to 10000)` then program stops:

> ~17 027 lines will be printed (out of 20 000).  No "ERROR" message
>   will be printed. No "took" message will be printed

**And will not be processing any futher.

But if I change exContext to `ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(null: Executor)` (global one) then in ends in about 10 seconds (but not normally).

```
~17249 lines printed
ERROR: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]
took: 10.646309398 seconds
```

**That's the question
:** Why with fixed ex-context pool it stops *without messaging*, but with global ex-context it terminates but with error and messaging?

and sometimes.. it is not reproducable.

**UPDATE:** I do see `"ERROR"` and `"took"` if I increase pool from 1 to N. Does not matter how hight N is - it sill will be the ERROR.

The code is here: https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/tree/master/src/main/scala/concurrency/apptmpl

and [here, doManagerStuff2()](https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/blob/master/src/main/scala/concurrency/apptmpl/managers/Manager1.scala)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea of what's going on. If you squint enough, you'll see that `map` duty is extremely lightweight: just fire off a new future (because doServiceStuff is a Future). I bet the behavior will change if you switch to `flatMap`, which will actually flatten the nested future and thus will wait for second `doServiceStuff` call to complete.

Since you're not flattening out these futures, all your awaits downstream are awaiting on a wrong thing, and you are not catching it because [here](https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/blob/master/src/main/scala/concurrency/apptmpl/managers/Manager1.scala#L39) you're discarding whatever Service returns.

---

Update

Ok, I misinterpreted your question, although I still think that that nested Future is a bug.

When I try your code with both executors with 10000 task I do get `OutOfMemory` when creating threads in `ForkJoin` execution context (i.e. for `service` tasks), which I'd expect. Did you use any specific memory settings?

With 1000 tasks they both do complete successfully.

Comment: and why it stops execution with one context and works ok with another? (I simplified my question)

Comment: here I put example where one may wait "on wrong thing": https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/blob/master/src/main/scala/concurrency/antipatterns/OneBasketExContext.scala
but in my question's example I wait on separate thing - on ex1 for waiting anther for doing.